# How can you link directly to an app reviews section on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

This used to work

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=XXXXXXXXX&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2
```

Since iOS 9 the user gets an error message:

> Your request produced an error, [newNullReponce]

What is the new url structure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code should take you to the app page on the App Store. As far as I know, there is no way to go directly to the app reviews anymore.

```
NSString* appId = @"APP_ID";
NSString* appUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@", appId];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appUrl]];
```

Comment: Yes, thats what I now use and it works, but the user must click Reviews after the initial link, shame.

Answer (score 0):

The new structure is: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id[your app id]?at=10l6dK"];`

Additional note that might help:
Here is my solution to implement a iOS app review popup.

You could just implement a UIAlert view that you call when you are ready, so in the following example you wuld call appReviewReminder when you want to fire the alert.

I'm thinking maybe you could do it on a randomized behavior, so that every 1 of 5 it will alert, keep track if the user already submitted review (kind of), or any number of ways :

```
-(void)appReviewReminder{

        UIAlertView *infoAlert;
         version = @"1.4.23"
        infoAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle: nil
                     message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"[Your App Version] V%@\nIf you enjoy [Your App Name] take time to give us a review, please press 'App Review'.",version]
                     delegate: self
                     cancelButtonTitle: @"Maybe Later"
                     otherButtonTitles: @"Submit Feedback",
                     @"App Review",nil];

        [infoAlert show];      
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {
        //"Review Later" so dismiss alert
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        //route user to your website's support page
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebsite.com/contactSupport.html"];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else{
        //route to iOS App Store URL
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id[your app id]?at=10l6dK"];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    }
}
```